# Using automator to remove empty spaces / desktops automatically?

Tags: automator, desktop, spaces, mission-control

I use Yabai for window management, and so I'm frequently opening new windows and sending them to new desktops. But as I close windows, this means that I end up with a large number of desktops with no windows on them.

I'm wondering if there's a way, possibly using Automator, to automatically remove desktops that don't contain any windows? Basically, whenever I close the last window on a desktop, it should be removed. So if my windows look like

```
[ Finder ]  [Firefox]   [Notes]
Desktop 1   Desktop 2  Desktop 3
```

and I close Firefox, I want the result to be

```
[ Finder ]  [Notes]   
Desktop 1   Desktop 2
```

Renumbering the desktops would be nice but is non-essential.

I can currently go into Mission Control and manually remove unused desktops, but this is annoying and cumbersome.

Note: [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141548/close-empty-desktop-spaces) is similar, but the answer is basically "you can use automator" and my question is "how?"